# Set up multiple WAP4410N AP with same SSID

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, networking, access-point, cisco-wireless

We are facing a WiFi connection issue in the prod environment at client place (a big hall, around 200ft x 150ft). Details:

Environment:

1. 4 Cisco WAP4410N Access points mounted on the pillars in the hall
2. All 4 AP are configured for` same SSID, same Channel (i.e. 6)
3. Two kinds of mobile devices

   - Motorola MC55 - Windows Mobile OS 6.5
   - Urovo i6300 - Android 7
   - Chainway C70/C71 - Android 6.0
   - Software Apps used for all the above devices are based on TCP/IP socket based. Messages are continously transmitted and received. Message size is around in KBs.
   - No DHCP enabled for any of the APs, Switch or even the Server. All the mobile devices mentioned above configured with 
     Static IPs.
   - Server is running on SUSE EL 11

Issue:
While roaming in the platform, MC55 works properly, almost no disconnections (assumed no packet loss). But with Android devices while roaming we experienced moderate to severe connection issues and packet losses.

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

I have shared the AP configuration details below:

```
[BASIC]
Host_Name=P18-AP1
Device_Name=WAP4410N
Language=en
IP_settings=0 ;0:static; 1:automatic
Ipv4_address=10.0.18.4
Ipv4_subnet_mask=255.255.255.0
IPv4_default_gateway=10.0.18.1
IPv4_Primary_DNS=0.0.0.0
IPv4_Secondary_DNS=0.0.0.0
IPv6=0 ;0:disabled; 1:enabled
IPv6_settings=0 ;0:static; 1:automatic
Ipv6_address=
Ipv6_prefix_length=0
IPv6_default_gateway=
IPv6_Primary_DNS=
IPv6_Secondary_DNS=
```

[Wireless_Basic]

```
Network_mode=7 ;0:Disable; 1: b only; 2: g only; 3: n only; 4: B/G mixed; 7:B/G/N mixed
Channel=6 ; 0..14; 0: auto channel
SSID1=P18-AP
SSID1_broadcast=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
SSID2=
SSID2_broadcast=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
SSID3=
SSID3_broadcast=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
SSID4=
SSID4_broadcast=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
```

[Radius_Server]

```
Primary_radius_server=
Primary_port_no=1812
Primary_shared_secret=
Secondary_radius_server=
Secondary_port_no=1812
Secondary_shared_secret=
```

[Wireless_security_1]
;

```
for SSID1
ssid=P18-AP
isolation_between_SSID=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
security_mode=3 ;1: WEP, 2: WPA-Personal, 3: WPA2-Personal, 4: WPA2-Personal Mixed, 5: WPA-Enterprise,
    6: WPA2-Enterprise, 7: WPA2-Enterprise Mixed, 8:RADIUS, 0: Disabled
isolation_within_SSID=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
authentication_type=1 ;0:open system; 1:shared key
encryption=2 ;64: 64 bit WEP, 128:128 bit WEP, 1: TKP, 2: AES, 3: AES+TKIP
Default_Tx_key=1 ; 1..4
```

[Wireless_security_2]

```
;for SSID2
ssid=
isolation_between_SSID=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
security_mode=0 ;1: WEP, 2: WPA-Personal, 3: WPA2-Personal, 4: WPA2-Personal Mixed, 5: WPA-Enterprise,
    6: WPA2-Enterprise, 7: WPA2-Enterprise Mixed, 8:RADIUS, 0: Disabled
isolation_within_SSID=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
authentication_type=0 ;0:open system; 1:shared key
encryption=0 ;64: 64 bit WEP, 128:128 bit WEP, 1: TKP, 2: AES, 3: AES+TKIP
Default_Tx_key=0 ; 1..4
key1= ;in Hex
key2= ;in Hex
key3= ;in Hex
key4= ;in Hex
PSK_key= ;in ASCII; The length of the key is from 8 to 63
Key_renew=0 ;in seconds
```

[Wireless_security_3]

```
;for SSID3
ssid=
isolation_between_SSID=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
security_mode=0 ;1: WEP, 2: WPA-Personal, 3: WPA2-Personal, 4: WPA2-Personal Mixed, 5: WPA-Enterprise,
    6: WPA2-Enterprise, 7: WPA2-Enterprise Mixed, 8:RADIUS, 0: Disabled
isolation_within_SSID=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
authentication_type=0 ;0:open system; 1:shared key
encryption=0 ;64: 64 bit WEP, 128:128 bit WEP, 1: TKP, 2: AES, 3: AES+TKIP
Default_Tx_key=0 ; 1..4
key1= ;in Hex
key2= ;in Hex
key3= ;in Hex
key4= ;in Hex
PSK_key= ;in ASCII; The length of the key is from 8 to 63
Key_renew=0 ;in seconds
```

[Wireless_security_4]

```
;for SSID4
ssid=
isolation_between_SSID=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
security_mode=0 ;1: WEP, 2: WPA-Personal, 3: WPA2-Personal, 4: WPA2-Personal Mixed, 5: WPA-Enterprise,
    6: WPA2-Enterprise, 7: WPA2-Enterprise Mixed, 8:RADIUS, 0: Disabled
isolation_within_SSID=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled
authentication_type=0 ;0:open system; 1:shared key
encryption=0 ;64: 64 bit WEP, 128:128 bit WEP, 1: TKP, 2: AES, 3: AES+TKIP
Default_Tx_key=0 ; 1..4
key1= ;in Hex
key2= ;in Hex
key3= ;in Hex
key4= ;in Hex
PSK_key= ;in ASCII; The length of the key is from 8 to 63
Key_renew=0 ;in seconds
```

[Wireless_Connection_Control_1]

```
;for SSID1
Connection_Control=0 ;0: disabled, 1:local, 2: Radius
Control_type=1 ;0: allowed the following local mac, 1: prevent the following local mac
Mac_01=
Mac_02=
Mac_03=
Mac_04=
Mac_05=
Mac_06=
Mac_07=
Mac_08=
Mac_09=
Mac_10=
Mac_11=
Mac_12=
Mac_13=
Mac_14=
Mac_15=
Mac_16=
Mac_17=
Mac_18=
Mac_19=
Mac_20=
```

[Wireless_Connection_Control_2]

```
;for SSID2
Connection_Control=0 ;0: disabled, 1:local, 2: Radius
Control_type=0 ;0: allowed the following local mac, 1: prevent the following local mac
Mac_01=
Mac_02=
Mac_03=
Mac_04=
Mac_05=
Mac_06=
Mac_07=
Mac_08=
Mac_09=
Mac_10=
Mac_11=
Mac_12=
Mac_13=
Mac_14=
Mac_15=
Mac_16=
Mac_17=
Mac_18=
Mac_19=
Mac_20=
```

[Wireless_Connection_Control_3]

```
;for SSID3
Connection_Control=0 ;0: disabled, 1:local, 2: Radius
Control_type=0 ;0: allowed the following local mac, 1: prevent the following local mac
Mac_01=
Mac_02=
Mac_03=
Mac_04=
Mac_05=
Mac_06=
Mac_07=
Mac_08=
Mac_09=
Mac_10=
Mac_11=
Mac_12=
Mac_13=
Mac_14=
Mac_15=
Mac_16=
Mac_17=
Mac_18=
Mac_19=
Mac_20=
```

[Wireless_Connection_Control_4]

```
;for SSID4
Connection_Control=0 ;0: disabled, 1:local, 2: Radius
Control_type=0 ;0: allowed the following local mac, 1: prevent the following local mac
Mac_01=
Mac_02=
Mac_03=
Mac_04=
Mac_05=
Mac_06=
Mac_07=
Mac_08=
Mac_09=
Mac_10=
Mac_11=
Mac_12=
Mac_13=
Mac_14=
Mac_15=
Mac_16=
Mac_17=
Mac_18=
Mac_19=
Mac_20=

[VLAN_QoS]
VLAN=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled
Default_VLAN_ID=0 ;1..4094
VLAN_Tag=0 ;0:untagged, 1: tagged
AP_Management_VLAN=0 ;1..4094
VLAN_tag_over_WDS=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled
WDS_VLAN_List= ;a,b,...,"a" is a VLAN ID. Different IDs divided by ",". 4 VLAN IDs should be set at most
VLAN_ID_4_SSID1=0 ;1..4094
Priority_4_SSID1=0 ;0..7
WMM_4_SSID1=1 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled
VLAN_ID_4_SSID2=0 ;1..4094
Priority_4_SSID2=0 ;0..7
WMM_4_SSID2=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled
VLAN_ID_4_SSID3=0 ;1..4094
Priority_4_SSID3=0 ;0..7
WMM_4_SSID3=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled
VLAN_ID_4_SSID4=0 ;1..4094
Priority_4_SSID4=0 ;0..7
WMM_4_SSID4=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled
```

[Wireless_Advanced]

```
802.11d=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled
Country_Region=276 ;1702: Asia, 208: Denmark, 1276: Europe, 246: Finland, 250: France, 276: Germany,
         372: Ireland, 380: Italy, 392: Japan, 528: Netherlands, 554: New Zealand, 578: Norway, 
         724: Spain, 752: Sweden, 756: Switzerland, 826: United Kingdom
Channel_bandwidth=2 ;0: auto, 1: 20MHz, 2: 40MHz
Guard_Interval=0 ;0: auto, 1: 400ns, 2: 800ns
CTS_Protection_Mode=0 ;0: disable, 1: auto
beacon_interval=100 ;20..1000
DTIM_interval=1 ;1..255
rts_threshold=2347 ;1..2347
fragmentation_threshold=2346 ;256..2346
Load_balance=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled
Load_threshold_4_SSD1=
Load_threshold_4_SSD2=
Load_threshold_4_SSD3=
Load_threshold_4_SSD4=
```

I have attached the mobile screenshots taken from WiFi monitoring app (WiFi Monitor)

[image: signal strength screenshot]
[image: signal strength screenshot]

[image: signal strength screenshot]

Comment: ;WAP4410N Configuration File - Version: 2.0.7.8

Comment: Why are you using the same channel? Use 1 6 11

Comment: A proper wireless site survey by a professional will give you WAP quantity, placement, frequencies, etc. Also, you probably want to use a wireless controller for your WAPs.

Comment: One can't up-rate @sergeyrar's comment enough. Do _not_ use overlapping channels. Quite possibly not related to the issue with roaming clients, but just as good Wifi practice to start with.

Comment: And: If that server is accessed by all the clients, move it to the wired part of the network. In general, WiFi suffers if there is heavy client-to-client-traffic, because each frame occupies the medium _twice_.  [WifiClient -> AP|AP->WifiClient]. That essentially cuts overall throughput by half.